# Support app: device cannot be selected

Tags: apple-id

Wondering if anyone else encountered this issue.

I have my main M1 MBP properly linked to my Apple ID and listed under My Devices for more than a year.

It’s also available at the initial stages of support request (either via Support app or via the website).

However, having selected this laptop at the initial stage, after I “describe my problem” it again asks to select a device—and this time it’s not in the list:

[image: screenshot of Get Support screen showing lack of relevant options]

Comment: My take from this is - you've told them your device, now they want to know what app or service you want to ask about.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, but the thing is all options presented correspond to either other devices (iPhone, iPad, Watch, but not Macbook that I started with), or Apple software services. It’s a catch-22: you select a device, describe a problem, then see options that *exclude* that device. I initially entered a laptop hardware problem, so there was no way to proceed without lying. (I had to enter a completely irrelevant problem to get support with my actual problem…) I am not sure whether it’s something to do with my Apple ID; I re-checked and all devices are correctly associated with it to my knowledge.